# 0 value method transaction

Tags: transactions, binance, method

Hey I have a question hope anyone can help me understand. I withdrew some USDC from Binance to my hardware wallet and noticed an automatic 0 value usdc method transaction about 5 min later. I withdrew to the same wallet before and never did it send a automatic transaction afterwards. Does anyone have an idea why it does this, I can' t make sense of it.

Transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9433b4564698fedc79f3cc0d105bb7bf27cf8c931e190c8725aad34bbeedca8e

[image: transfer after]

Comment: This was asked recently. Anyone can make a 0 value transaction for any address for some tokens, and for some reason, someone is doing exactly that.

Comment: But how can there be a 0 value transaction "OUT" from my wallet to another wallet without me approving or doing anything? I could understand a 0 value transaction coming in but is it possible to do one going out without me interfering?

Comment: It's not from your wallet. Anyone can send a transaction to the USDT contract which says "please give me 0 USDT from Vonwelzen's wallet" and the USDT contract can say "ok done"

Answer (score 1):

I think I found this might be an attacking attempt. What the attacker tries to do is use the same first and last letter as a transaction previously done so when you try to transfer a new amount you could accidently copy the wrong adress (of the 0 value transfer) and send the hacker funds. More info here:

https://mirror.xyz/x-explore.eth/cL3d_CyNujXq8XY7ueP4omNXx_IY1EG5Dz0FD0vJ90M